# knockout pass additional parameters to subscription function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

What I want to achieve is to create subscription for model properties. This subscription function should call WebApi via Ajax updating property value in database. For ajax call I need three paramaters: "`fieldName`", "`fieldValue`" and "`modelId`", ajax will update database row based on those three parameters.

I have many properties and all of them need the same functionality, so I do not want to subscribe for each property individually, so I found a following suggestion:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.withUpdater = function (handler) {
    var self = this;    
    this.subscribe(handler);    
    //support chaining 
    return this;    
};
```

Add this is how it is "attached" to observables:

```
self.ModelId= ko.observable();
self.CompanyName = ko.observable().withUpdater(update);
```

where `update` is some js function outside model.

However, I have problem, because I am not able to pass three paramaters to `update` functions (or also I can say in another words - I need to be able to get `viewModel.ModelId` property value inside `update`, as well as `propertyName`).

```
function update (propertyName, propertyNewValue, anotherPropertyValue) {
  //do ajax update 
}
```

As an example for CompanyName property it will be:

```
update("CompanyName", "New Company value here", 3),
```

where

```
3 == viewModel.ModelId
```

Comment: I updated my answer and am curios what route you went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but the following will work:

First, add a target object to the withUpdate method:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.withUpdater = function (handler, target, propname) {
    var self = this;   

    var _oldValue;
    this.subscribe(function (oldValue) {
      _oldValue = oldValue;
    }, null, 'beforeChange');

   this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
     handler.call(target, _oldValue, newValue, propname);
   });

       return this;     
};
```

The update subscribe function will get scoped to the target property:

```
var update = function (propertyName) {
   console.log('propname is '+ propname + ' old val: ' + oldvalue + ', new val: ' +  newvalue + ', model id: ' + this.ModelId());
}
```

Now you will need to use it a little differently.

```
  self.CompanyName = ko.observable().withUpdater(update, self, "CompanyName");
```

An example  http://plnkr.co/edit/HhbKEm?p=preview

I couldn't get the scope of the withUpdater function to be that of the object without explicitly passing in the target and a string for the company name.

Comment: It gives me propertyValue and not propertyName in update function first paramater.

Comment: I've updated both to include the old value, property name, new value, and model id although I wonder if there is a more eloquent way to do it without having to pass in a string for the property name.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your function as a variable outside of the 'fn' scope.

```
var dataservice = 'my class that has the data calls';

var altFunc = function () {
        
    return ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var currentItem = this().filter(function (item) {
        
// Do knockout stuff here and return your data
// also make calls to the dataservice class
        
        }, this, dataservice);

        
    };


ko.observableArray.fn.someNewFunctionality = altFunc;
```